# How to compile and run MULTIPLE java programs from another java program without knowing their class names?

Tags: java, compilation, runtime

Assume there is a zip file containing 4-5 simple java programs. I want to write a code that unzips the file(this part is easy), compiles and runs all the .java files in it.

So far I have been able to compile and run individual java programs using another java program, although I have to know their class names. What if I only know the directory where they are located but not their names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally to run any program, you need to know the name of the program that you will execute.
Now, if "all" the classes on your zip file will be run, then you can:

1. Unzip the files.
2. Read all the files names (classes) and put
   them in a String[].
3. Parse the String[] and execute each name
   (class) on the array as a class; you may need Reflection [enter link
   description here](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-reflection).

Let me know if you need more help.

Try something like this:

```
    File directory = new File("c:\temp");
    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    for (File thisClass : files) {
        Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        try {
            Process process = runTime.exec(thisClass.getName());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process process = runTime.exec("What string should I include here?");
I am using Eclipse on Linux and java -classpath <directory> is not working.